# Acumatica Customize Process Shipments Add branch field from PO Receipts

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to add fields to the grid on the Process Shipments screen for PO Receipts when the "Prepare Drop-Ship Invoice" action is selected.  Specifically, I want to add the POReceipts.BranchID field.

I've studied the source code, and I see where different select commands are run based on the selected action, but I don't understand what drives the grid to show the different set of columns.

I looked in the screen designer in the customization editor, and I don't see a different view or anything, hopefully I'm just missing something simple.

Thanks
Scott

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solved your mystery.  First create a user field for SOShipment.

```
    #region UsrReceiptBranchID
    [PXInt]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName="Receipt Branch ID")]
    [GL.Branch()]

    public virtual int? UsrReceiptBranchID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrReceiptBranchID : PX.Data.BQL.BqlInt.Field<usrReceiptBranchID> { }
    #endregion
```

Next is the key part.  I extended the data view delegate, and added an extra query to pull the POReceipt branch, when the Filter is Drop-Ship.

```
    public virtual IEnumerable orders()
    {
        List<SOShipment> records = Base.orders().RowCast<SOShipment>().ToList();
        if (Base.Filter.Current.Action.Contains("Drop"))
        {
            foreach (SOShipment sOShipment in records)
            {
                POReceipt receipt = PXSelect<POReceipt,
                    Where<POReceipt.receiptNbr,
                    Equal<Required<POReceipt.receiptNbr>>>>.Select(Base, sOShipment.ShipmentNbr);
                if (receipt != null)
                {
                    SOShipmentExt shipExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>(sOShipment);
                    shipExt.UsrReceiptBranchID = receipt.BranchID;
                }
            }
            return records;
        }
        else
        {
            return records;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Chris, thanks so much for  you help on this.  When I have the line  [GL.Branch()] on the dac extension for usrReceiptBranchID field I get this error.  "Error: The entry form (ID:SO302000, title: Shipments) cannot be automated. Invalid column name '[SOShipment_SOShipment].[UsrReceiptBranchID]'  It compiles fine, but I get that error when accessing the screen unless I removed that line.  Any Ideas?  Thanks again.

Comment: I replaced the [GL.Branch()] attribute with this selector attribute and that seems to have solved my issue.  [PXSelector(typeof(GL.Branch.branchID), SubstituteKey = typeof(GL.Branch.branchCD), DescriptionField = typeof(GL.Branch.acctName))]